# Changing dummy variable value from 1 to column name, and then creating a list that I can compare rows with

Tags: python, pandas, list, rename, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
A    B    C

1    0    0
1    1    0
0    1    0
0    0    1
```

I want to replace all values with the respective column name, so that the data looks like:

```
 A    B    C  

 A    0    0  
 A    B    0   
 0    B    0   
 0    0    C
```

Afterwards, I want to create a column that is a list of all column values like so:

```
 A    B    C         D

 A    0    0   ['A','0','0']
 A    B    0   ['A','B','0']
 0    B    0   ['0','B','0']
 0    0    C   ['0','0','C']
```

Finally, I want to group by column D and count the number of occurrences for each pattern.

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `mul`

```
df.mul(df.columns).replace('',0)
Out[63]: 
   A  B  C
0  A  0  0
1  A  B  0
2  0  B  0
3  0  0  C
#df['D']=df.mul(df.columns).replace('',0).values.tolist()
```

Comment: I'm  getting an error while running your answer: `TypeError: Could not operate Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object') with block values cannot perform __mul__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>`

Comment: @PedroLobito what is your pandas version ?

Comment: `>>> pd.__version__
'0.20.3'` - Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: @PedroLobito do you still have the issue after update pandas ?

Comment: Not anymore after updating to pandas `0.23.4`, nice answer. +1

Comment: @wenyoben this no longer appears to work in version .25

Answer (score 1):

There must be *cleaner* ways to achieve this, but the you can use:

```
for column in df:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(str).replace("1", column)
df["D"] = df.values.tolist()
```

---

**Output:**

```
   A  B  C          D
0  A  0  0  [A, 0, 0]
1  A  B  0  [A, B, 0]
2  0  B  0  [0, B, 0]
3  0  0  C  [0, 0, C]
```

---

PS: [W-B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771856/797495) is the *cleaner* way.